# MySQL - Rename selected columns with the same name from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting the same column from two different tables, but want to use `select as` to make them different names.

```
(SELECT letter AS letter_1, sex AS sex_1 FROM `celebs_a` LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT letter AS letter_2, sex AS sex_2 FROM `celebs_b` LIMIT 1)
```

That query returns this:

```
letter_1 sex_1
a        1
b        1
```

But, I want it to return this:

```
letter_1 letter_2 sex_1 sex_2
a        b        1     1
```

How can I make that query return each value as a different column name? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(letter_1) AS letter_1, MAX(sex_1) AS sex_1,
       MAX(letter_2) AS letter_2, MAX(sex_2) AS sex_2
FROM (
    (SELECT letter AS letter_1, '' AS letter_2, sex AS sex_1, 0 AS sex_2
     FROM celebs_a
     LIMIT 1)
    UNION
    (SELECT '' AS letter_1, letter AS letter_2, 0 AS sex_1, sex AS sex_2
     FROM celebs_b
     LIMIT 1)
) AS derived_table_must_have_an_alias
```

You can easily extend this to selecting multiple columns from each table. Just put `0` or `''` as a placeholder for those columns in the other table.

Comment: I ran that query but got this error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Now it's saying: #1054 - Unknown column '0AS' in 'field list'

Comment: I tried it with and without the 'OAS' before, but it still had an error. Thanks for the update, but it's just returning '0' for each value.

Comment: I didn't realize they were strings, not numbers. I've changed it to use `MAX` instead of `SUM`.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. That last update works for letter_1 and sex_1, but returns empty results for letter_2 and sex_2.

Comment: Sorry, needed some extra parentheses to keep the last `LIMIT 1` from applying to the whole union.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT letter AS letter_1 FROM `celebs_a` LIMIT 1) AS letter_1,
    (SELECT letter AS letter_2 FROM `celebs_b` LIMIT 1) AS letter_2;
```

Updated:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT letter ... FROM celebs_a ...) AS letter_1,
    (SELECT letter ... FROM celebs_b ...) AS letter_2,
    (SELECT sex ... FROM celebs_a ...) AS sex_1,
    (SELECT sex ... FROM celebs_b ...) AS sex_2
```

Or Barmars's approach would be better (it runs only 2 SELECT query)

Comment: Hey that works! Can you edit your answer to my updated question though? I want to select 2 columns from each table. Is there a way to do it where I wouldn't have to do a bunch of select statements? Ultimately I'm going to pull about 20 columns from each table.